# Spring Cloud Rest Template Injection Failure

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have some simple Spring Boot/Cloud applications annotated with @EnableOAuth2Sso.  It worked fine until I decided to 'upgrade' my dependencies by generating a project using the Spring Initializr site.  (The reason for this was I am interested in trying out Spring Cloud Sleuth).

I generated the project using Spring Boot 1.3.0, plus all the dependencies for Zuul, Eureka, Sleuth, Security, etc...

Here's a sample app:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableEurekaClient
public class SSOClientApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SSOClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
@RestController
public class SSOClientController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String doAction() {
    return "Hello World";
}

}
```

Now all my apps that were using OAuth2/SSO fail with the below exception.  Can anyone help?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userInfoRestTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$UserInfoRestTemplateConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at uk.co.aquilauk.automationframework.SSOClientApplication.main(SSOClientApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration$1.postProcessAfterInitialization(MetricsInterceptorConfiguration.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.BUILD-20151118.000750-167.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 20 common frames omitted
```

EDIT: Here is a bit more:

```
2015-11-18 15:43:19.520 ERROR 10116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.       [Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userInfoRestTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$UserInfoRestTemplateConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4583) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userInfoRestTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$UserInfoRestTemplateConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userInfoRestTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$UserInfoRestTemplateConfiguration: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:220) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:356) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.SsoSecurityConfigurer.oauth2SsoFilter(SsoSecurityConfigurer.java:50) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.SsoSecurityConfigurer.configure(SsoSecurityConfigurer.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration.configure(OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration.java:57) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:199) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:290) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:67) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fc33ec5b.init(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:105) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ce3acbb2.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$4(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ce3acbb2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$361e0f4a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ce3acbb2.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration$1.postProcessAfterInitialization(MetricsInterceptorConfiguration.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.BUILD-20151118.000750-167.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 52 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You should demonstrate that `nested exception` for us. I mean share, please, more StackTrace.

Comment: I've just added a bit more - it's not much.  My main goal is to get the Sleuth stuff working, but whenever I introduce the SSO/Oauth stuff, things seem to break.  I'm not clear on what versions of each project will work together.

Comment: Open an issue. Looks like a bug.

Comment: OK - which project?  URL please (so I get it right)..:-)

Comment: I'm going to say https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues because that's where the error is happening.

Comment: @TimWebster, what are you dependencies, I'm unable to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in spring-boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/8708a07a98ee9d4279293cbaf1d2ab36820dae2d

It's available in snapshots and will be in 1.3.1.